# Problem in setting focus on inputfield in mozilla

Tags: visualforce, jquery

i have one inputfield with some styleClass. i am using jquery on onBlur event to set focus on that inputfield. it is working fine in IE and Chrome but in mozilla it loses focus. what's the issue?

jquery method

```
function validatePhoneLength(ele) {
          ele.value = ele.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "") ;
          if(ele.value.length < 10 && ele.value.length != 0) {
             alert('Phone number must contain atleast 10 digits');
             $('.phone').focus();
        }
  }
```

vf code

```
<apex:inputfield styleClass="phone" onblur="validatePhoneLength(this);" 
value="{!Information[Info.fieldPath]}" />
```

Comment: Could you put some example code?

Comment: added javascript and vf code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem to setting the focus was that you must wait for the event 'blur' to complete. The solution is to use a timer.

```
    <script>

    function validatePhoneLength(ele) {
        ele.value = ele.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "") ;
        if(ele.value.length < 10 && ele.value.length != 0) {
            alert('Phone number must contain atleast 10 digits');
            setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById(mid).focus(); }, 30);
        }
    }

    </script>

    Input <apex:inputField value="{!account.phone}" 
                           styleClass="phone"
                           onblur="validatePhoneLength(this);" 
                           id="myPhone"/>

    <script>
        var mid = '{!$Component.myPhone}';
    </script>
```

Comment: Great!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: this seems really hacky and dependent on the page.  What is blur doesn't complete in 30ms?